# url rewrite error with splash on wamp

Tags: url-rewriting, wamp, slash

this is `test.php`:

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

and this `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+) test.php?id=$1
```

when i try `test/8` , php says:

> Notice: Undefined index: id

but when i edit .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test-([0-9]+) test.php?id=$1
```

and try 'test-8' code works fine!!

why??